# Is it ok to have a lot of params in sql WHERE {params}?

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, where-clause

So, I have a `SELECT` and my `WHERE` in that select adds sometimes a lot and sometimes not of `x = 1 OR x = 2`, I imagine there could be even like 100 of them.

Is it okay to do that? Or it can kill the perfomance?

Here is the more visual example of it

```
string sqlString = String.Format("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE {0}",
                                  stringWithAlotOfORsStatment)
```

The `stringWithAlotOfORsStatment` is generated depending on the situation and what user selected

Not sure if this question makes any sense :L

Comment: but only if you want to expose yourself to SQL Injection attacks and conversion bugs

Comment: It is ok to have a lot of parameters, it's not OK to concatenate strings to create sql statements. This is a security hazard as it's an open door for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Be aware that this isn't safe for SQL Injection. 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: I'd recommend testing it out and if there is a performance issue run a sql profiler to determine what indexes can be added to your table to improve performance.

Comment: Please be more specific. You can use LINQ to create a query where you can add/remove `Where` clauses. You can construct the Where expression at runtime too. You can replace multiple `ORs` like the one you posted with `WHERE x IN (1,2,3)`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the injections. Params that comes to that string are checked way before but was wondering if it won't kill it somehow if there would be too many of those WHERE OR statetment  @PanagiotisKanavos  the stringWithAlotOfORsStatment string is formed from an array and values from that array(int) comes from database

Comment: As for performance - impossible to answer. The specific conditions matter, as well as any underlying indexes. Bad conditions will cause degradation, eg applying functions to fields. Lack of indexes will always harm performance

Comment: @bunakawaka your multiple ORs can be replaced with a single `x IN (1,2,...)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do I just place x IN (arrayHere?)

Comment: You can write `WHERE x in (1,2,3)` just as you can write `WHERE x = 5`. That's just one of the operators allowed by SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for help. I will have to test it little bit and see how it goes

Comment: we had this conundrum, and we did at one time build a giant IN statement - the .net routines acted on arrays of integers, and it would not have been possible to inject harmful SQL by them.  We found a faster/efficient way was to use .net SQL BulkCopy (I think it was) to drop all of the int's into a table, then use a join + an identifying key on the table.  The large IN comparison did become slow when it had several thousand integers in it, the temporary values in a table beat it.

Comment: so my answer would be that we did find that performance could be degraded with large WHERE statements - we sped it up by populating a table of values that we INNER JOINed to - possibly a temp table could be used.  Was populated by .net SQL bulk statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace multiple `X=1 OR X=2...` statements with a single `X IN (1,2,3)`, eg:

```
SELECT * From SomeTable where X in (1,2,3)
```

Instead of using String formatting to pass the list of values, I'd suggest the use of LINQ and EF, or Dapper.NET to create a safe query.

In a LINQ to EF Array or List.Contains maps to the `IN` clause:

```
var ids=new []{1,2};
var results = from r in ctx.SomeTable
              where ids.Contains(r.x)
              select r;
```

In Dapper you can pass the array as a parameter:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE x IN @ids"
var results = conn.Query(sql, new { ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3});
```